# Shell Scripting command not found Error

Tags: shell

I'm new to programming with shell and want to ask what is wrong with my code?

```
#!/bin/bash
#DHT11
SCRIPT="/var/www/ErnestynoFailai/scripts/DHT 11 4"
#DHT22
#SCRIPT="/root/to/folder/DHT 22 4"
#AM2302
#SCRIPT="/root/to/folder/DHT 2302 4"
HUMIDITY=`$SCRIPT | grep "Temp" | awk -F " " '{print $7}'`
TEMPRATURE=`$SCRIPT | grep "Temp" | awk -F " " '{print $3}'`
#-a = AND = &&
while [ $HUMIDITY=="" -a $TEMPRATURE=="" ]
do
    $HUMIDITY=`$SCRIPT | grep "Temp" | awk -F " " '{print $7}'`
    $TEMPRATURE=`$SCRIPT | grep "Temp" | awk -F " " '{print $3}'`
done

echo "$HUMIDITY"
echo "$TEMPRATURE"
```

I'm getting:

```
line 14 or 15 =26: or =: command not found...
```

Comment: what is the output of `type -p /var/www/ErnestynoFailai/scripts/DHT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. These lines are not returning anything, or at least a string:

   ```
   HUMIDITY=`$SCRIPT | grep "Temp" | awk -F " " '{print $7}'`
   TEMPRATURE=`$SCRIPT | grep "Temp" | awk -F " " '{print $3}'`
   ```

This is causing `=: command not found` errors.

2. Your while condition needs to be

   ```
   while [[ $HUMIDITY == "" && $TEMPRATURE == "" ]]
   ```

Finally, while not causing problems, `TEMPERATURE` is misspelled, which might cause you grief later on.

Comment: Thanks, its worked and stops :) Huh.. Shell script is so strange :D

Comment: Great! Yeah, shell scripting is wild and not intuitive compared to more common programming languages, esp. when it comes to conditions (brackets, and whether one or two, have different meanings depending on the shell too, for instance).

Comment: More one question where is `$SCRIPT | grep "Temp" | awk -F " " '{print $7}'` how can i whrite at one line? get temperature and hum? And check it?

Comment: If the awk field position doesn't change, then replace your `grep` with `egrep "Temp|Humidity"`. Otherwise, you could write a function that executes that line, but takes an argument for which field position to extract.

Answer (score 0):

Variables have to be assigned without leading `$`:

```
HUMIDITY=`$SCRIPT | grep "Temp" | awk -F " " '{print $7}'`
TEMPRATURE=`$SCRIPT | grep "Temp" | awk -F " " '{print $3}'`
```

Comment: Thanks, but now looping every time ;/ why it is not stopping when HUMIDITY and TEMPERATURE is not empty?